# Where can I find an Amulet of Akatosh?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to build all the shrines in my houses in the in Skyrim's Hearthfire expansion.

I've been able to find every amulet and build all the shrines so far, except for Akatosh.

Where can I find an Amulet of Akatosh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Amulet of Akatosh is a random drop item.

[Some](http://www.gamespot.com/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/forum/amulet-of-akatosh-61958054/) [people](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615804-/61951929) have reported being able to buy it at [Radiant Raiment](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Radiant_Raiment) in Solitude. [Other](http://demo2.ask.com/answers/2282235/how-to-get-the-amulet-of-akatosh) [sources](http://www.skyrimwiki.com/Amulet_of_Akatosh) claim it can be found in a chest aboard the [Orphan's Tear](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Orphan's_Tear).

Comment: +1, thanks.  I've been trying Radiant Rainment over and over (that is how I got 3x of all the rest of the amulets that are not easy to find), but maybe I have just been unlucky since I have never seen Akatosh there.

Comment: After many more visits, confirmed that you can find amulet of Akatosh at Radiant Raiment.

Answer (score 2):

I married Ysolda from Whiterun and she randomly had it a few times when I was buying/selling with her.

Comment: Always marry Ysolda. =]

Answer (score 2):

The amulet of Akatosh can be found in caves, forts , can be sold by your wife or husband, and can be found in jewelry / apparel stores.

Answer (score 0):

You know that Draugr at the end of Bleak Falls Barrow? I got mine off of him, and sometimes other draugr. After I decapitated a Stormcloak, I found one on his body. Pickpocket guards to see if they have them. But it's random and will not always be guaranteed to find them. Radient Rements almost never has them with me... just Julianos todos los días.

Answer (score 0):

I just wait 48 hours in Radiant Raiment continously until it pops up. Helps when you're building the shrine in your home. I always find myself needing Akatosh and Zenithar

Answer (score -1):

Go dungeon diving (although there might not be too many dungeons with amulets), attack Forsworn camps, defeat forts owned by Bandits, (usually one of the best places is around the middle of the map, Falkreath and Bleak Falls Barrow, on my first account I encountered an EXTREMELY hard fort to conquer. I was a level 36 Orc with Heavy Armor, Two-Handed and Bow with Ebony arrows. There was a Pyromancer or something and he kept spamming Fireball (not FireBOLT) and I wasted all my Ebony arrows (like around 63) with an Ebony, refined, enchanted bow and he didnt even get to half health and kept healing and killed me in 3 shots (the only reason why i was hiding in the mountains to kill him was because i had 100% weakness to fire because i was a vampire) I forgot what it was called, but it was just below winterhold in the mountains), etc. There is a LOT of places where you can find amulets.

(lol this is a lot of writing for how to find an Amulet of Akatosh)

Comment: "There is a LOT of places where you can find amulets" is because ["The Amulet of Akatosh is a random drop item."](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/92107/4163)